# CFS hardlimit in cgroups

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cgroup

I recently moved to KVM. Previously I was using xen and its capping feature in credit scheduler. Where we can set a cpu cap for a VM. I was searching for a similar feature to set hard limits on a VM in KVM. I recently found that cgroups has a concept called quota which lets us set a hardlimit for VM (process) in kvm. I am currently using centos 6. I checked cgroups but I can see only the ability to provide cpu shares and not quotas.Even libvirt has the support for this feature from version 0.9.4(As per the site), I am currently using libvirt 0.9.4 but when I use the command to set cpu quota , I get invalid option error. Can someone please tell me what am I missing and what should I do to enable that feature in cgroups to set hardlimits. Thanks !

- Sethu

Answer (score 1):

Currently cpu.shares only define the lower bound of cpu allocation, defining the upper bound(aka capping) is called CPU bandwidth control in the Linux kernel community [CPU bandwidth control for CFS](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36669.html). But I'm afraid this feature hasn't made its way to the mainline kernel yet, nevertheless the patch is available ,  for example the [7.2 version](http://lwn.net/Articles/452584/)